# Can't get the value of a tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm just starting to use BS4 and I just can't seems to find why i can't extract the text in the following table -> http://pastebin.com/MCQC7wLY

This is my code:

```
    for team in soup.find_all('tr'):
    print team.a.string
```

I get the following error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

I also tried other stuff like

```
for team in soup.find_all('tr'):
    print team.find('a').string
```

But I'm always getting the same error.

this is what team.find('a') return

```
<a href="/entry/688922/event-history/7/">FC Lasne</a>
```

I would like to extract "FC Lasne"

It's driving me mad because usually I just do find('a').string and its just work

How should I proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first `tr` in your example does not have any `a` tags in it.

You could just ignore any `tr`s without links:

```
for team in soup.find_all('tr'):
    link = team.find('a')
    if link == null:
       continue
    print link.string
```

Though you could just do:

```
soup.find_all('a')
```

Comment: Oh god how could I missed that the 1st tr didnt have any a... That will teach me to code for long period of time. Thanks for the help